# Tag synonyms and edits

Tags: discussion, tagging, edits

Is this edit correct?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/87614

I thought that `sql-server-2008` automatically includes `sql-server` tag? Or was I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general SQL Server tag is useful for people looking to answer questions about SQL Server in general.

The specific version tag is useful for:

- answerers, so they know what features and syntax may or may not be used in their solution
- future readers, so they know whether answers there *might* be more likely to be relevant to their problem

It may seem like sql-server-2008 would "include" sql-server but this isn't quite true. If you *only* tagged sql-server-2008, and someone didn't know (or care) if a solution was "only" for SQL Server 2008 (and what solution *is* only for a specific version), they might not find it, because maybe they're using SQL Server 2012 and wouldn't have thought to search for sql-server-2008.